# How to deploy K8S on raspberry pi

Tags: docker, kubernetes, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to follow simple tutorial for setting up kubernetes cluster on raspberry pi.
First, I have done following steps on my first, main node on RPI4 runing raspbain32 lite:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1
sudo dphys-swapfile swapoff
sudo dphys-swapfile uninstall
sudo apt purge dphys-swapfile
curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh
sudo usermod -aG docker pi
sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
   with: {
           "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
           "log-driver": "json-file",
           "log-opts": {
             "max-size": "100m"
           },
           "storage-driver": "overlay2"
         }

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
   with: deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kubeadm kubectl kubelet
```

and now I'm trying to initialize main node with:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.17.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.18.0.0/24 --service-dns-domain=domain.pl --ignore-preflight-errors=Mementer
```

Unfortunattelly with errors:
When I run:
journalctl -xeu kubelet
the output is following:

```
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.585661    4345 kubelet.go:278] "Adding static pod path" path="/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.585823    4345 kubelet.go:289] "Adding apiserver pod source"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.585931    4345 apiserver.go:42] "Waiting for node sync before watching apiserver pods"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: W0204 08:40:18.590181    4345 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://192.168.50.5:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.590531    4345 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://192.168.50.5:6443/
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: W0204 08:40:18.594769    4345 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://192.168.50.5:6443/api/v1/services?limit=5
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.594980    4345 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://192.168.50.5
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.648906    4345 kuberuntime_manager.go:248] "Container runtime initialized" containerRuntime="docker" version="20.10.12" apiVersion="1.41.0"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.651230    4345 server.go:1231] "Started kubelet"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.652507    4345 kubelet.go:1351] "Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet" err="failed to get imageFs info: unabl
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.653927    4345 server.go:150] "Starting to listen" address="0.0.0.0" port=10250
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.656572    4345 event.go:276] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"raspi.16d088909b39
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.658288    4345 server.go:410] "Adding debug handlers to kubelet server"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.658329    4345 fs_resource_analyzer.go:67] "Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.672306    4345 volume_manager.go:291] "Starting Kubelet Volume Manager"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.674276    4345 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:147] "Desired state populator starts to run"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: W0204 08:40:18.682743    4345 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "https://192.168.50.5:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.683013    4345 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "https://192.168.
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.687401    4345 controller.go:144] failed to ensure lease exists, will retry in 200ms, error: Get "https://192.168.50.5:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namesp
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.752861    4345 kubelet.go:2347] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network pl
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.787657    4345 kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node \"raspi\" not found"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.864342    4345 kubelet_node_status.go:70] "Attempting to register node" node="raspi"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.867907    4345 kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://192.168.50.5:6443/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp 192.168.50.
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.888396    4345 kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node \"raspi\" not found"
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: E0204 08:40:18.890847    4345 controller.go:144] failed to ensure lease exists, will retry in 400ms, error: Get "https://192.168.50.5:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namesp
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: I0204 08:40:18.906450    4345 kubelet_network_linux.go:57] "Initialized protocol iptables rules." protocol=IPv4
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: panic: unaligned 64-bit atomic operation
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: goroutine 349 [running]:
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: runtime/internal/atomic.panicUnaligned()
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/unaligned.go:8 +0x24
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: runtime/internal/atomic.Load64(0x732b4ec)
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_arm.s:286 +0x14
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*containerData).updateStats(0x732b380)
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]:         /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager/container.go:676 +0x438
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*containerData).housekeepingTick(0x732b380, 0x72907c0, 0x5f5e100)
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]:         /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager/container.go:587 +0x104
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*containerData).housekeeping(0x732b380)
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]:         /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager/container.go:535 +0x3bc
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]: created by k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/google/cadvisor/manager.(*containerData).Start
Feb 04 08:40:18 raspi kubelet[4345]:         /workspace/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.c om/google/cadvisor/manager/container.go:122 +0x2c
Feb 04 08:40:19 raspi systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit kubelet.service has exited.
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 2.
Feb 04 08:40:19 raspi systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- The unit kubelet.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've no idea what wrong with it. Did I missed something?
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You can look at this open issue on GitHub: [kubelet 1.23.0 (cAdvisor 0.43) panic on arm64 / Raspberry PI OS32 #106977](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/106977)

Comment: Yes. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Isn't that issue about a 32-bit OS ? Mine is `pi@raspberrypik8smaster:~ $ uname -m
aarch64`